# function arguments in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to wrap my head around the way positional and keyword arguments work in python, and, it seems, I'm failing rather miserably.

Given a function with a call signature `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args,**kwargs)`, it can be called as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3]
y=[5,6,7]
plt.plot(x,y,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

Now, I'm trying to wrap it into something which I can call as `mplot(x,y,'ro-',...)` where `...` are whatever arguments the original function was ready to accept. The following fails miserably, but I can't really figure how to fix it:

```
def mplot(x,y,fmt,*args,**kwargs):
   return plt.plot(x,y,fmt,*args,**kwargs)

mplot(x,y,'ro-')
```

Any pointers to a way out would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It should work (at least it does for me - Python 3.1)... any details on the error or what it did vs. what you expected?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just call `plot` as it is. What's motivating this question?

Comment: This code looks actually fine - what is the *real error*?

Comment: "fails miserably" is useless as error description

Comment: Thanks to everybody. Indeed, that was a stupid question, with the real error in a different part of the code. The error's fixed, the lesson learned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it this way:

```
def mplot(x,y,fmt,*args,**kwargs):
   #do stuff with x, y and fmt
   return plt.plot(*args,**kwargs)
```

I'm assuming that your intention is to consume the `x`, `y` and `fmt` in your `mplot` routine and then pass the remaining parameters to `plt.plot`.

---

I don't believe that this is actually what you want (I can see that `plt.plot` wants to receive `x`, `y` and `fmt` and so they should not be consumed). I had deleted this answer but since your posted code apparently works, I'll leave this visible for a little while and see if it provokes the real question to be revealed!

Comment: @ David Heffernan: I'm actually going to accept your answer, since I saw it, and then figured the actual error in the actual code, which was way down the line, and not in fact related to this issue with the arguments.

Comment: @David Heffernan: As to your question what motivates all this fuss: given a set of points, fit them by a certain function, then plot the points *and* thea best-fit line. After copying this the 3rd time around, I thought I'd give this a name :-).

Comment: @Zhenya: Please let rest of us all so to know what was the original problem. It doesn't make really sense to just accept something and let rest of us wondering what's your real problem and solution for it. Thanks

Comment: @eat: If you're so curious, here it is:  
dtc=[('L1','float64'),('L2','float64'),('Tc','float64'),('dTc','float64'),                                     ('yc','float64'),('dyc','float64'),("tag",np.str_,16)]  
crossings=np.zeros(len(pairs),dtype=dtc)

using just a "string" in the numpy dtype generates segfault. Why is that I have no idea, but this (np.str_,16) seems to work as long as the length of the string is <16 characters.

Comment: @Zhenya: I'm not curious, but consider how many different persons eventually will try understand what is going on with your question! BTW, your comment is not really readable, please consider to update it on your question. Thanks

Comment: @eat @Zhenya It would make a lot more sense for the real solution to be posted as an answer by Zhenya. I could then delete this and Zhenya could answer his/her own answer. The downvote was a bit pointless. I said I was going to delete this once it was resolved and I only undeleted the answer to try to help provoke some sense.

Comment: @David: I'll be more than happy to up vote if what you proposed happens. Thanks

Comment: @eat I've just tried to delete this and I can't because it's the accepted answer!!

Comment: @eat @David: Since the actual problem in the original script was in no way related to what I asked, and since the question itself is, uhm, trivial (at least in hindsight), posting an answer does not make any sense. I now vote to delete the question itself.